# How to open datepicker on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office365

[Here](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/datepicker) we have a datepicker, which can be opened by clicking on input. I would like to change it and to open it by click on my own components(button),or by click on another office365 components.How can it be performed?
I thought, that it was possible to realize using setState.

```
this.setState{showDatePicker: !this.state.showDatePicker}
```

But unfortunatelly it's not so.Now I have next component, which can be opened by click on `input`:

```
const DayPickerStrings = {
    months: [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December'
    ],

    shortMonths: [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'Jul',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec'
    ],

    days: [
        'Sunday',
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday'
    ],

    shortDays: [
        'S',
        'M',
        'T',
        'W',
        'T',
        'F',
        'S'
    ],

    goToToday: 'Go to today',
    prevMonthAriaLabel: 'Go to previous month',
    nextMonthAriaLabel: 'Go to next month',
    prevYearAriaLabel: 'Go to previous year',
    nextYearAriaLabel: 'Go to next year'
};

export class ToolbarDatePicker extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        firstDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek.Sunday
    };
}

    render() {

        let { firstDayOfWeek } = this.state;
        let placeholder="Outlook - ";
        return (
            <div>
            <DatePicker firstDayOfWeek={ firstDayOfWeek }
                        strings={ DayPickerStrings }
                        placeholder={ placeholder }
                        isMonthPickerVisible={ false }
                        />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your code? and what have you tried?

Comment: @chsdk added code

Comment: I am not expert with React but there are thousands of people that can help ;)

Comment: I hope on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the documentation https://dev.office.com/fabric#Implementation:

you can use `componentRef` just as you would a ref

so...

```
class Foo extends Component {
  handleClick(){
    // their APi is not documented well
    this.datePicker._showDatePickerPopup()
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
      <DatePicker
        label='Start date'
        onSelectDate={ date => this.setState({ value: date }) }
        componentRef={instance => this.datePicker = instance} />

      <button type='button' onClick={e => this.handleClick()} >open</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

based upon source here:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/DatePicker/DatePicker.tsx

you can probably also `setState` on the datepicker instance to alter it, something like `this.datePicker.setState({isDatePickerShown: true})`

Comment: It works,thank you very much. One more question. How can I hide that input,which appears by default?

Comment: you need it to mount so you get a reference to an instance, so conditional render is not an option. you can only do that via CSS - either add `display: none` or translate it out of view. `className` is curried (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/DatePicker/DatePicker.tsx#L181) so you can just add `className='is-hidden'` and define that. also, accept the answer :)

Answer (score -3):

```
$('#theIdOfTheButton').click(function() {
   // call the library here
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
$("#buttonId").click(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("show");
});
```

```html
<button id="buttonId" type="button">Button</button>
```

Comment: I need to do it in react(